how to handle exceptional case for SpringBoot @JmsListener
I'm not expert yet using Spring @JmsListener() annotation for receiving JMS message. For exceptional case e.g. Deserialization failed or other failure case, are we able to catch it? or we use registered ExceptionListener and ErrorHandler?
option1:
@JmsListener(destination="***", containerFactory="ListenerFactory")
public void receive(@Payload Object payload) {
try {
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}


option2 (ExceptionListener will be a customized one):
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(new JmsQueueErrorHandler(""));
        factory.setExceptionListener(new javax.jms.ExceptionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onException(javax.jms.JMSException e) {
        
      }
    });


